# Anyway to serve /static from a prefixed URL (e.g. /client/static) with npm start?

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, create-react-app, nginx-ingress

I've been working on this for a while and can't seem to get anywhere.

Basically, I have an ingress controller for a microservice that has a URL of:

```
- path: /client/?(.*)
  backend:
    serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service
    servicePort: 3000
```

However, when I navigate to `192.168.64.4/client` (this is the `minikube ip`) I don't see anything because the URL `npm start` is using for the static files is `/static`. I need to change it to `/client/static`.

Is that possible?

I know that `homepage: "/client"` is not an option since that is just for production. This is in CRA so I'd like to avoid ejecting it.

EDIT:

Added my current `ingress.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  name: ingress-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /client/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: server-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 5000
```

The `/api` route works fine because Django has a built in way of handling prefixed paths. Without doing this, it will not serve `static` files properly particularly for the `admin` portal:

```
FORCED_SCRIPT_NAME = '/api'
STATIC_URL = '/api/static/'
```

ReactJS, apparently does not *in development*. You can manually navigate to `/client/static/js/bungle.js` and see the `.js` there. So somehow `/client` needs to be prefixed to the `/static/` path.

I did try changing the following:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
```

This created some odd behavior.

- On the `/client`, still the same issue, but can't find the `/static` files at any location (e.g., `/client/static`, `/static`, etc.)
- On the `/api`, can't get it to serve anything with, or without, `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`. The ingress is getting into the Django, but says it can't match any of the routes, which is incredibly strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the rewrite annotations in your ingress definition, I think that in your case it would be something like this:

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
```

The $2 gets replaces with the capture (.*) of the match, then if you try to access /client/static the resulting rewrite would be /static ... this should work in theory, give it a try!
If this didn't work let me know to try to figure out why

Here is a similar definition for my resources as well, not exactly as your case, but I am using the rewrite and it is working here.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: proxy-ingress
  namespace: repoflow-s3-proxy-demo
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /resources.repoflow.com/resources/$2
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: s3.amazonaws.com
spec:
  rules:
  - host: s3-proxy.repoflow.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /resources(/|$)(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: resources-external-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Thanks for the help; however, still running into the same issue. I've updated my original question.

Comment: Try replacing /client/?(.*) with /client(/|$)(.*) in your ingress

Comment: Ok, I'm getting behavior now as I did with `$1` and `/?(.*)` now. Still, client isn't serving because assets are still trying to be served from `/client/static`.

Comment: Try adding the next annotation: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet : rewrite_log on;   after this, check the logs of the nginx controller pods, you should see a "rewritten data" section, that might give you a clue of what is the issue